# If the laws of conservation of energy remain the same, can I change everything else?

Tags: physics, energy, universe

This universe is boooring.

I don't care that today's science is basically magic, and being a programmer is the equivalent of a fantasy ''rune shaman''.
I want actual magic, the type of magic people believed in before industry, before the Renaissance.

In our universe, we had steampunk, dieselpunk, and soon we live in those boring cyberpunk stories.
But we never had DUNGEONPUNK, and I want to be real.

Floating castles, alchemy to turn lead into gold, psionics, telekinesis, people using magic that allows them to pass thru solid object unharmed and so on, stuff like that.

So in this new universe, if the laws that govern how energy work remain the same, can I change everything and have a functional universe?

Or maybe the correct question might be, what is the (hopefully) small list of physical laws of the universe that I can't change if I want this imaginary universe to stiff function?

Comment: It is a very short list indeed. Starts and ends with 0 actually. The issue really is that our laws of Physics are really approximations for one but also are extremly interconnected. For example, why is Gravity as weak as it is. Well that is related to the Cosmological Constant, speed of light, number of dimensions, what Energy is, how strong the fundamental forces are etc. If you, for example, make the Electromagnetic Force a bit weaker everything collapses into black holes. Make it a bit stronger, well everything still may collapse into black holes or just never form complex structures.

Comment: I feel like username Cataphract should have an avatar of a cataphract, not a cutiepie.

Comment: @ErikHall Another way to think about it is that all the rules of physics are in always in play, in all places, at all times. So when you change one aspect in one place, you are changing everything, everywhere.

Comment: I strongly urge you to delve into Fullmetal Alchemist. Its core tenet is the law of **equivalent exchange**, which is essentially conservation of mass (somewhat of a spoiler alert: and of energy). Counter to what is generally suggested, I'm going to suggest FMA and _not_ FMA Brotherhood. While FMAB is the better of the two series, the original FMA's story resolution is very relevant to what you are considering here, more so than FMAB's ending.

Comment: You can have some of those things but they will have other consequences, I doubt you can have a alternative consistent scientific model that looks exactly like a magical world. For example if passing through objects is possible with some magic that's probably something that also will happen randomly to objects/animals and even people. Floating castles probably mean that there's also just a lot of random things floating in the air, like it does in the sea in our reality.

Comment: It sounds a bit like [Darkover](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Darkover), where people with telepathic, telekinetic and other "magical" abilities such as precognition and manipulation of matter are able to do these things by the power of their minds aided by peculiar blue crystals. Violations of the law of conservation of energy are not postulated, instead, it is a "non-causal science."

Comment: Unless the plot revolves around doing detailed, careful scientific experiments, the actual "laws of physics" don't matter much: Pick your rules and stick to them, as @stig-hammer describes in his answer.  If your principal characters are scientists (or science-flavored magicians) and the plot involves them making discoveries, then you'll want to know how those experiments go, and how they relate to everyday life... but trying to reverse-engineer a universe of "fundamental rules" with the constraint of "desired high-level tech" is a multi-century project.

Comment: There are a few pieces of fiction that actually do this. Diaspora by Greg Egan, for instance, posits what the universe would look like if there were five physical dimensions instead of three. The unfortunate conclusion that the all reach is that such a universe is still boring, just a different kind of boring. If you want specific results, you need to specify them and then work backwards.

Comment: Why are you tying yourself even to conservation of energy? Why not change everything and still retain a functional universe?

Comment: Why not just make the laws of physics less "strict"?

Comment: @Flater: Ah FMA; my CS instructor was talking about it. But hand one of them a modern physics textbook and you will learn the true meaning of power. If you can do lead into gold; you can do some more interesting things.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simple answer: change which forces & particles are plugged into energy conservation. Real physics is far more... specific than anything that idea determines.

If magnetism didn't exist and someone made it up in a story, it might seem like magic violating EC. But it doesn't violate EC: the energy of an object thereby affected has a kinetic component dependent on its speed and a potential component dependent on its position. And, with a suitable electrical power source, one can turn electromagentism on and off, and thereby update other objects' total energies. If you invent new forces by analogy with EM, you can make physics seem very different despite EC. The implications for floating castles are obvious.

Alchemy is [actually real](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nuclear_transmutation); it just uses lots of energy. *How much* energy depends on the finer details of how nuclei work, so feel free to reduce the energy scale to match chemistry. (That ruins [otherwise amazing nuclear power](https://xkcd.com/2115), but I suspect you don't mind that.) You could make the reason it doesn't happen on its own one of needing a nuclear catalyst.

For psionics, imagine something analogous to X-ray scans that see the inside of brains, together with read/write abilities due to evolution or magic. Bones block real X-rays (which are EM radiation), but not your fake cousins of them. For telekinesis, suppose there's a "magnetism" that can work on anything, but is customisable, e.g. by mixing several forces to tune to one object.

Solid walls block us in a real-life version of [this](https://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/SomeKindOfForceField) trope, but dark matter could cut through it. If dark matter [has its own kind of EM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dark_radiation) to hold it in solid clumps, you could wrap yourself in a wall-bypassing cloak. (How you'd get a hold of the cloak with mechanical forces is a subtler issue; if the two kinds of EM mix a little bit, that might just be feasible without a wall being harder to pass through than swimming in treacle.)

Answer (score 26):

**New rules are not intrinsically more exciting than old rules.**

/This universe is boooring./

Your problem is that you find laws and order boring.  They are, too.  Boring and predictable.  The things you list as exciting are exciting to you because they break the rules.

If you set up new laws and new orders that are also predictable, those too will become boring.  If everyone is floating thru walls with your new rules it is no more exciting than those people climbing up stairs with the current rules.  New sets of rules are not intrinsically more exciting than old sets of rules.

If you consider chaos and transgression and iconoclastic wildness to be exciting, set your story in the world of ordinary rules and physics.  Then when your character breaks the rule and turns poop into pure gold (that still looks like a piece of poop) it will cause excitement!  If a person invents a device that allows them to accomplish things previously impossible (like flying) that too will be very exciting.

Comment: It would be boooring for the characters but it could be quite fun for the readers. Think of Greg Egan's Orthogonal and Dichronauts.

Comment: Clearly, you need the rules to unpredictably change with time to keep them exciting. Think of the excitement when waking up and not knowing if energy or momentum will be conserved today.

Comment: For a great illustration of this, see Brandon Sanderson's _The Lost Metal,_ set in the world of _Mistborn_ where they explicitly refer to advancements in the magical "Metallic Arts" as technological progress.  There's a conversation where the characters explicitly deny that the (familiar to them and well-studied) Metallic Arts are magical in nature, and concede that magics used by a visitor from a different world of the Cosmere are probably not really magic, but that guy over there with the *really weird* powers?  Yeah, that's totally magic.

Answer (score 16):

There’s a foundational theorem in fundamental physics called Noether’s Theorem that proves there’s a conservation law associated with every symmetry of the universe. If you want your universe to have time-translation symmetry (on the broad scale it looks the same today as it did yesterday and will tomorrow) then you have to have conservation of energy. If you want the universe to look the same wherever you go, you have to have conservation of momentum. If you want the universe to look the same in all directions, you have to have conservation of angular momentum. And so on — the less obvious symmetries of the standard model lead to conservation of electric charge, quark colour, and so on. (“Looking the same” basically means that the laws of physics look the same, not that the universe has to be completely homogenous.) (Technically speaking, the conserved item has to be described by a Lagrangian, but almost everything in modern physics is.)

Comment: For reference, [Emmy Noether](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Emmy_Noether) (1882–1935) was a German mathematician. Albert Einstein called "the most important woman in the history of mathematics". As a Jewess, she had to leave her country when the National-Socialist Workers' Party came to power, and she spent the last years of her life in the USA.

Comment: Though it should be mentioned that Noether´s Theorem is not exactly a law of nature. As we know Energy is not conserved in an expanding universe. All of these conservation laws only really apply in local, closed systems. The universe could be closed but it probably isnt. So on a global scale quantities are not conserved

Comment: @TheBlender: Noether's Theorem is a *theorem*, which is one step above any empirical laws of physics. *If* you want an universe where what you computed yesterday will still be valid tomorrow, *then* Noether's Theorem says that energy is conserved. If you don't want such a universe, the theorem does not apply.

Comment: That dosnt change the fact that Energy is not conserved for us. The idea is rather simple, anything past the cosmological horizon can never interact with us and we can never interact with it. Due to the expansion of the Universe, new matter and hence energy falls beyond this Horizon. So, the Energy in the observable universe is not conserved. Again, at a global scale it might, but that dosnt matter to us since we cant observe this global state.

Comment: @ErikHall While it’s true that time-translation symmetry doesn’t apply on the widest scales of an expanding universe with a Big Bang, it (and thus conservation of energy) most certainly applies to us, because we can’t come anywhere close to conducting experiments on the kind of scale that would be needed to show a discrepancy.

Comment: @MikeScott Conservation laws only break down in expanding spacetime. So when bodies are gravitationally not bound. On Earth or basically anywhere else we can go Gravity is stronger than the expansion (for now, probably forever). So on a local scale these laws mostly apply. But nothing is true local. If you shot a Laser away from the Galaxy that Energy is gone forever if it dosnt get lensed back by a black hole or neutron star. So no system is truly local and or truly isolated. So no conservation technically applies. But for all intend, they do.

Comment: @ErikHall how is energy not conserved in an expanding/contracting spacetime? The fact that stuff falls beyond the horizon does not matter at all, because the "observable universe" is not a thing, but a changing concept, which depends on a specific location.

Comment: @Chieron "The fact stuff falls beyond the horizon dosnt matter-" this is not true. The instance anything goes beyond the cosmological horizon we will never be able to interact with it anymore. And no new information about it can ever return. Hence, its energy is gone. Because there is no physical way of optaining it. It is true that this depends on your location in spacetime. But this only makes the issue worse C2

Comment: @Chieron C2, it is worse because now the Amount of energy depends on where you are. Which is not how conservation works. Someone 100 Billion lightyears away will have a differnt total for the energy in their Observable Universe, and they too will see that energy leaves that bubble.

Comment: @Chieron C3, you can play this game with everything. The fundamental result dosnt change. Even at a local scale no quantity is actually fully conserved. Not even in black holes since they radiate away Energy via Hawking Radiation. Which eventually will leave the Cosmological horizon of the BH and bada bing bada boom, conservation of energy is out the window. You might say "Well the energy is still there right ?" Probably, but we cant interact with it so we dont know. All we know is that the energy in the universe decreases over time.

Comment: @ErikHall No, all we know is that the definition of the observable universe changes over time. At best, this turns it into an open system, for which energy conservation does not apply. But it is a weird open system, where the contents also change, when switching to another point in the same system. Stuff beyond the horizon is not gone, it does not matter that we cannot interact with it anymore. Of course, idealized closed systems do not truly exist, but arguing with inflation is splitting hairs.

Comment: @ErikHall The statement that "energy is conserved" means that energy can't be created or destroyed. It doesn't mean that energy can't go to a place where we can't observe it any more. There's no theoretical or practical sense in which energy is not conserved.

Comment: You know; I've always wondered if we don't need Lagrangian at all; and if we can set up everything with Kinematic equations. The classical equations of motion can be expressed as a large finite sum in pure kinematics and doesn't even need to contain things we normally assume. But I have no idea if the same can be done in GR.

Answer (score 9):

### Yes

I'm going to focus on this:

> can I change everything and have a functional universe?

You can have psionics and telekinesis and magic and *assert* that energy conservation holds true. You can envision a functional universe with those things. Unless you are [Greg Egan](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Greg_Egan), you're not obligated (and frankly, not encouraged) to give the reader a rundown on the whole of physics in your magical universe.

---

Even the smallest changes have far-reaching consequences. I've heard that even if little old insignificant neutrinos just arbitrarily had the interaction cross-section of an equivalent energy photon, the Sun would get about 3% brighter due to all the trapped neutrinos and its lifespan would shorten by about 500 Myr or so, which might've tipped the primordial Earth into a greenhouse state.

There are no small changes or additions you can make that don't radically alter the shape of the cosmos.

Comment: Of course, _Earth_ being a greenhouse doesn't matter if you're not trying to fit your fantasy to Earth. Other planets might become _more_ hospitable.

Answer (score 4):

The rules of your universe are entirely up to you.

If you aren't writing hard SF, all you need to do is be *consistent* about your rules. Establish them early and don't break them later.

The rules are there to limit the characters and create suspense.  This goes for both protagonists and antagonists.  If the reader get the feeling that the author just invents a new super-power whenever they need one, much of the suspense is lost.

Conservation of energy is a good rule.  It fits with the readers intuition of  how the world works and is also a limit that can be bypassed by a clever character.

Entropy increasing is a another good rule, but one that is harder to work with.  Deciding exactly what entropy means can be difficult.

Conservation of momentum is a good rule, but a very annoying one.  It prohibits all sorts of fun stuff like a small person throwing really big things around.

What is magic in your universe?  You need to decide that before you start writing about it.

One option is that magic is an extra form of energy, and the manipulation of that energy. There should be strict limits to how much energy a mage can handle at once.

Another option is that magic allows you to decrease entropy.  This allows all sorts of fun effects, but you have to be careful to not make  magic TOO powerful.

There are many other options.

Let me repeat the main point: Establish your rules early and stick to them.

Comment: "Conservation of momentum... prohibits all sorts of fun stuff..." until you apply magic to the problem, and then anything can be permitted by the rules of magic. 

Answer (score 4):

If your objection to physics is that a consistent set of rules makes things boring, then *any* consistent set of rules will suffer from the same problem. But if it's just the fact that our specific rule set is just too boring (and I can think of a number of chemists who would argue against that point), then perhaps there's something more fun we can do for you.

As others have noted, how your fictional universe works is entirely up to you. You get to decide what works and what doesn't, and you don't ever have to explain why or exactly how everything works. As long as there aren't any glaring inconsistencies that can't be hand-waved away by being the result of a particularly powerful mage, and you don't give the readers any reason to complain at your ruleset, then you'll be fine.

In fact having a magical setting is already a pretty good start for slipping in some pretty outrageous things. The Will and the Word was pretty outrageous, but the Belgariad was one of the best-selling fantasy series. Tolkein apparently didn't even bother to figure out how magic worked in his world, but everyone lapped up LotR. At least the Elfstones almost made sense in the Shannara series.

Point being, don't worry about the why, just write the what.

---

Now that's out of the way, let's look at the actual question...

Given that your universe works, you can leave pretty much all of the physical laws exactly the same as they are here. The two fundamental forces (yes, two: strong nuclear and electro-weak) are enough to account for basically all of the interactions except those having to do with space curvature (gravity). You just have to mix in a new force, field or other interaction effect that your magic can operate on to affect things.

Of course you don't even need to go that deep. What you want is some high-level rules that determine how things work at the engineering level. The average engineer doesn't care about the way that photons mediate the electro-weak force to produce chemical bonds, van-der-Waals force, normal force and so on. They care about the structural integrity of the materials and the way pressure is produced when you combust a propellant in a sealed chamber. You'd be hard pressed to find a bridge engineer who didn't know how to factor gravity into his designs, but few of them could derive the gravity equation from Einstein's field equations.

So don't worry about fundamental forces, particle interactions, whether or not there's a mediator particle for the thaumic field and what happens when you bash those particles together. Work up some engineering guidelines for how to actually use magic and let the Ponder Stibbonses of the world waste their lives on useless esoteric knowledge. Your average wizard is more interested in how to make flashy light shows or summon extra-dimensional entities to scrub their unmentionables anyway. (Which to be fair probably need scrubbing after their last summoning spell grabbed the wrong kind of extra-dimensional entity.)

Maybe start with figuring out how a squishy human brain can handle effects requiring megajoules of energy without the spill-over turning your skull into a pressure cooker. Using simple magic shouldn't have the sort of results we saw in Kingsman... although the pretty smoke clouds were a nice touch, I imagine exploding brains to be a little less aesthetic.

Comment: "Tolkein apparently didn't even bother to figure out how magic worked in his world" I wouldn't be too sure about that. It obeys two conservation laws.

Comment: @Joshua Did it do so consistently? Nobody knows, because the vast majority of the magic in the story was glossed over - unlike more important details like the color of the leaves on the third tree from the right of some random rock. The magic was never fleshed out anywhere near as much as the scenery.

Comment: Seems pretty consistent to me; and changed far less in the legendarium than large chunks of its timeline.

Comment: @Joshua The fact that the magic system in the LotR universe *seems* to have some sort of consistent rules (which are never actually explained) is a far cry from saying definitely that it "obeys two conservation laws." The rings themselves appear to be capable of breaking physics in a number of ways. The One Ring's invisibility function appears to break conservation of energy.

Comment: It obeys its own conservation laws. While I can't predict what can be done; I can predict the cost of everything because of the rules it does follow.

Comment: @Joshua Pretty sure you *believe* that you can predict costs, but I'm unconvinced. Since Tolkein never actually provided detailed mechanics for his system of magic I highly doubt that your certainty is based on what he wrote but rather some things that you've intuited, or things that others have added to the canon. You're welcome to your opinion, but that's all it is.

Answer (score 2):

It is your universe and your rules.

As long as it is not self-contradictory, it can work.

Caveats:

1. If you have multiple small particles interacting, the whole thermodynamics (not only the energy conservation) will emerge by itself.
2. You can introduce whatever new particle interactions you want, but in most cases you will not actually need something much different from what we have here. We do have a lot of stuff, in fact. Just make some of it FDA approved.
3. Telekinesis is somewhat easy, but how exactly you pass thru the wall without sinking in the floor? Not being self-contradictory is HARD.